# C# RegEx, first match

Tags: c#, regex

I have next string:

```
String a = "someThing({Some text}); OtherStuff({Other text});";
```

I need to get the text included in '{' and '}' inside the 'someThing({...})';

I wrote:

```
var data = Regex.Match(a, @"(?<=someThing\(\{).*?(?=\}\)\;)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[0].Value;
```

But as a result in data I get the whole string 'a'. My expected result - "{Some text}"

Thanks for any advance.

Comment: Your regex works well: http://ideone.com/4gOx5e

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte his expected output is `{Some text}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=someThing\()({[^{}}]*})
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/31

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match zero or more characters but not of `}`, or `}` which was present just after to `something({`

```
(?<=someThing\({)[^{}]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hA9vA7/5)

If you want the output to contain `{}` braces then you need to get out the opening curly bracket from  lookbehind.

```
(?<=someThing\(){[^{}]*}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hA9vA7/6)

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/0EnEwo)

Comment: Maybe because this doesn't capture the `{` and `}`, maybe because it doesn't check for a closing `)`.